# Laravel E-commerce fetch 1 product to cart to order

Tags: php, laravel

I'm watching a tutorial on YT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQ2MeChuHVY&t=733s but the dude only has a (BUY ALL) button where the user's cart will go to order.
this is my ProductController

```
public function order()
    {
        $user_id = Session::get('name')['id'];
        $product = DB::table('cart')
            ->join('products', 'cart.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->where('cart.user_id', $user_id)
            ->select('products.*')
            ->get();
        return view('order-product')
            ->with('product', $product);
    }
```

I only want 1 product to proceed to order. but I don't know-how please help me

Comment: With the given `order` function, it's impossible. `cart` table has every product selected by the user. You have to prevent the user to add more than one product to the *cart*.

Comment: so there's no way to fetch 1 product?

Comment: To get just one of the selected products use `$product = DB:table('cart')->...->select('products.*')->take(1);`. Notice the `take(1)` instead of `->get()`. BUT, what's the purpose of the user selecting 'N' products and your code randomly crop the content for a randomly chosen single product?

Comment: i just want to take 1 product to the cart. but I don't know how :/